# How to detect device/emulator layout (landscape/portrait) is changed

Tags: android, android-layout, layout

Duplicate of [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2881122/how-to-know-device-emulator-layout-landscape-portrait-is-changed).

I am not able to add comment to the existing question that's why I have ask new question.

There is one solution in the above question "if your Android device is in landscape mode and you are loading a layout the android system will look if this layout file exists in the /res/layout-land folder. If it does not exist in this folder it will load the layout from the normal /res/layout folder."

But some how it is not working for me. I have added folder called land in layout folder also added xml file with same name, but it is still loading xml file from the main layout folder , when my screen is in landscape mode.

Is there any other solution ?

Comment: Look at this link on Android open source project https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=13189 , from what I read is a problem with the emulator

Comment: @GhostDerfel is there any other way I can detect that my layout is changed.

Comment: The worst method I can imagine is to calculate the height and width of your screen, but this is just a poor workaround (also need to test)

Comment: Did you try to run your app on a physical device?

Comment: @ArtooDetoo I don't have one. But I got the solution.

Comment: OK, share it and post your answer, then mark it as answered.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16566769/change-user-interface-when-device-change-the-orientation-android) is the link of the answer.

It just has to do with SDK version(11 and 13).